# CORS error on signalr with react client set up

Tags: reactjs, signalr

I am trying to set up signalr with react js and trying to receive value from backend (asp.net), my code are following

```
const signalR = require("@aspnet/signalr");


  useEffect(() => {
   
    const createHubConnection = async () => {

      const hubConnect = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl("http://82../notificationhub")
        .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
        .build();
      try {
        await hubConnect.start();

      } catch (err) {
        alert(err);
      }
    };

    createHubConnection();
  }, []);
```

`hubConnect.start()` is not working and and I am getting CORS error `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://82../notificationhub/negotiate' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.`


package version in `package.json`,
`"@aspnet/signalr": "^1.1.4",`

Full error message

[image]

Is there anything from client side I can do ?

Comment: try those lines: `var cors = require('cors');    
app.use(cors({credentials: true, origin: 'http://localhost:3000'}));`

Comment: Do I need to put that in react code ? I don't use nodejs in backend by the way. Backend uses asp.net.

Answer (score 2):

Like the error says, you can't use "*" or `AllowAnyOrigin` on the backend when using credentials. The SignalR client *uses* credentials so you need to explicitly specify which origins are allowed on the backend.

See the doc for details https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/signalr/security?view=aspnetcore-3.1#cross-origin-resource-sharing